# Find all objects that have an associated object with a certain property

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have an `Order` class that `has_many :shipments`. How can I use `Order.find` to return all the order objects whose *newest* shipment was created after a certain time (say, in the last hour)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Order.find(
  :all,
  :joins => :shipments, 
  :select => 'distinct orders.*', 
  :conditions => ['shipments.created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.hour])
```

The `:joins` ensures that you get orders that have shipments and the `:conditions` ensures that you only get shipments created in the last hour.

The `:select` means you only get one instance of each order in case an order has multiple notifications in the last hour.

I'm not sure the 'newest' stipulation is important as, if any shipment has been created in the last hour then the newest shipment will also match that condition.

Comment: "I'm not sure the 'newest' stipulation is important as, if any shipment has been created in the last hour then the newest shipment will also match that condition." -- Answer: I am an idiot.